# How to convert from int to wchar_t*?

Tags: c++

I did it like this:

```
static wchar_t* Convert1(tDWORD data) 
{
  wchar_t result[10];
  swprintf(result, sizeof(result) / sizeof(*result), L"%d", data);
  wprintf(L"[%ls]\n", result);
  return result;
}
```

And it didn't work, I guess because of stack memory has been cleared after return (Could someone explain to me why?). Then I tried like this:

```
static wchar_t* Convert2(tDWORD data) 
{
  wchar_t* result = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 10);
  swprintf(result, sizeof(result) / sizeof(*result), L"%d", data);
  wprintf(L"[%ls]\n", result);
  return result;
}
```

And it works, but I get only first digit of any number, and not the whole number. How to do this the right way ?

Comment: You get only one digit because result it's just pointer to heap (no syntax sugar as ordinal array), so sizeof(result) == sizeof(wchar_t*) means just ordinal pointer (4 or 8 bytes on most machines), sizeof(*result) == sizeof(wchar_t) (2 or 4 bytes), so sizeof(result)/sizeof(*result) != size of your array in wchar_t.

Comment: All local variables within a function disappear when the function returns. Local variables are typically implemented by allocating space on the stack, and when the function returns, it pops all of its locally allocated stack variables. Another way to think of this is to realize that local variables only exist as long as their parent function (or statement block) is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a string stream and a by-val wstring, such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

typedef uint32_t tDWORD;

static std::wstring Convert1(tDWORD data)
{
    std::wostringstream os;
    os << data;
    return os.str();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    tDWORD dwTest = 1024;
    std::wstring res = Convert1(dwTest);
    std::wcout << res << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
1024
```

Sorry I had to fake the typedef. Hope it is close to what you were using. The major benefit of doing this is all the memory management, conversion, etc, is handled for you by the library, having to hand-roll near-nothing on your side.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
static wchar_t* Convert1(tDWORD data) 
{
  wchar_t *result = new wchar_t[10];
  swprintf(result, 10, L"%d", data);
  wprintf(L"[%ls]\n", result);
  return result;
}
```

You tried to return the adress of the local variable (array) - local variables are cleared after returning of their scope. That's why you say that the memory was cleared. Also, allocating memory like this: `wchar_t result[10]` is allocating memory on stack. Allocating like this: `new wchar_t[10]` is allocating memory on heap.

Also, I replaced `sizeof(result) / sizeof(*result)` with just `10`. You cannot measure array capacity in C++, unfortunately :)

You can also use your `wchar_t* result = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 10);` instead of my `wchar_t *result = new wchar_t[10];` - my solution is only a bit clear, but it does the same.

Comment: I know, but that was in original question. That's the only reason why I didn't touch it.

Comment: I would prefer using [`std::wostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) myself, and just pull the `.str()` out when finished, returning a std::wstring` by-value.

Comment: You should touch it to give a correct answer. Edit: Oh I see you did.

Comment: @WhozCraig - feel free to provide your own answer containing **your** solution of the problem :)

Comment: In a nutshell, raw pointers should not own memory. There simply is no reason for that. In addition, this code is prone to overflows due to a fixed-sized buffer. 10 is *just* not big enough for all values in a DWORD – it would fit without null termination. But in addition, what happens when the data type is changed from DWORD to something else? Not a good idea. Granted, you guard against overflows, but you then get a wrong result, that’s not any better.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are right - but please note that the question owner's code has got the same mistakes :) I think you should add comment to the question too, and propose how to fix everything that you mentioned. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you're returning a pointer to a buffer on the stack, which will be destroyed when your function returns. In the second case you're allocating memory which the caller will have to be responsible for.

Try this:

```
static std::wstring Convert1(DWORD data) 
{
  const size_t bufferSize = 10;
  wchar_t result[bufferSize];
  swprintf(result, bufferSize, L"%d", data);
  return result;
}
```

or for a more C++ aproach...:

```
static std::wstring Convert1(DWORD data) 
{
  std::wostringstream stream;
  stream << data;
  return stream.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Or you could allocate the string/buffer space in the function that calls `Convert1()`, and pass it as another parameter in the call.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of `result` as a string of characters, which is a natural enough to think.  However, severely speaking, `result` is not a string of characters but rather *the address of the initial character* only.  Therefore, `sizeof(result)` does not do what you think.  Try `wcslen()` or `wcsnlen()`—though, really, what you might prefer to do is to learn C++-style strings.

Regarding `Convert1()`, you are right:  `result` is a local array, allocated on the stack, deallocated when its function returns.

By the way, your `Convert2()` may leak memory, depending on how its caller handles it.  You might prefer to have it return a `std::shared_ptr` or, better, `std::unique_ptr`, instead of a plain pointer for this reason.