# How to create 2d array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2D array(1 column) like this:

```
typedef wcha_t* ACHAR_ ;

    ACHAR_** value;
    value = new  ACHAR_* [5];  //create matrix 5x1
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      value[i] = new  ACHAR_[1]; ;
      for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
      {
        wstring s=std::to_wstring(i);
        value[i][j] = fcv_constAchar_to_Achar(s.c_str());
      }

    }
    msgbox_info(value[0][0]);  //
    msgbox_info(value[1][0]);
    msgbox_info(value[2][0]);
    msgbox_info(value[3][0]);
    msgbox_info(value[4][0]);
```

However, all value return L""; instead 1,2,3,4,5.

How to fix this code?

Comment: Do you want 2-D array whose elements are strings? Or characters (character is not the same as string)? Or numbers? I think you can remove much of the confusion by simplifying the code. But you must decide what you want your code to do.

Comment: It's `typedef`, not `typedefine`. And please do **not** typedef pointers, that's just hiding away information without any further value (sure, MS does such stuff all the time, but that doesn't change anything about being *bad* practice).

Comment: Hi @anatolyg, Thanks for the reply. in mycode, each element of array is wchar_t*. the reason i use ** because i want to pass this parameter to the function.  can i do this?

Comment: `ACHAR_** value;` now produces a tripple pointer (`wchar_t***`) – is this really what you want?

Comment: Hi @Aconcagua, exactly this pointer.

Comment: What is `fcv_constAchar_to_Achar`?

Comment: Hi @molbdnilo, my bad habit. it simply removes const (convert i to wchar_t*)

Comment: Your code looks OK (excluding bad practices). Maybe the problem is in another place, like your `fcv_constAchar_to_Achar` function. I suggest preparing a [mcve]. Replace your `msgbox_info` by some standard output methods (like `printf`) so people would be able to reproduce and understand your problem.

Comment: Then you're storing dangling pointers, and the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: Hi @molbdnilo, please point me to a correct approach.
I want to initialize an array(dynamic) can accessible by the index [row][col], then they are passed into a function that takes the ACHAR_** parameter.

Comment: not sure, it seems that its value is depending on wstring s. do i need to set `value[i][j]=new wchar_t` ?

Comment: `value[i][j] = new wchar_t[sufficiently_large_size];` – now you have allocated a memory buffer to which you can write to. Have a look at [swprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) to print a number to. About sufficently large size: Consider how many digits you want to print plus a trailing null-character finalising the string. For `unsigned int` you can get at most 10 digits, for `signed int` the same plus potentially the minus sign, so you'd need to be able to store at most 12 characters (32-bit int provided). I'd go with powers of to and allocate 16 bytes then.

Comment: Hi @Aconcagua, In the loop, value[i][j] is correctly L"1",L"2",.., but after breaking out of the loop ,all is gone (L"")  .I will try check it again

Comment: You'll have much less hassle around memory management if you use STL types. In your case, `std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>>` appears to be appropriate.

Comment: Hi, Temporarily I use this approach instead use wstring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17598054/15569855. it' working for me now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why, by the way, an 5x1 array at all? Wouldn't a one-dimensional array of length 5 of wide C-strings be just as fine?

Comment: Hi @Aconcagua, i'm usually used to working with 2darray so i'm just trying to find a way instead of using vector, although it seems risky but i think everything will be fine when the data written to file and end up at there.

Comment: @YenDang Well, that's rather the C-way of doing it. But this is C++, so what prevents you from learning the C++ way of doing stuff? Once gotten used to, you can write much safer code even more quickly...

Comment: @Aconcagua, maybe since I'm working on some old libraries but I'll gradually adapt to what you say. these are really attractive. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [regular](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/regular) types instead of pointers here. You were filling your array with pointers to objects that ceased to exist soon after.

```
std::array<std::array<std::wstring, 1>, 5> value;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        value[i][j] = std::to_wstring(i);
    }
}
msgbox_info(value[0][0].c_str()); 
msgbox_info(value[1][0].c_str());
msgbox_info(value[2][0].c_str());
msgbox_info(value[3][0].c_str());
msgbox_info(value[4][0].c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a std::vector or a std::array. Or a std::vectorstd::vector<wchar_t> if you really want to.

But this work on my end :

```
    typedef wchar_t wchar;
    wchar** value = new wchar* [5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        value[i] = const_cast<wchar*>(std::to_wstring(i+1).c_str());
        std::cout << (char)value[i][0]<<' ';
    }
```

Comment: That's also an array of dangling pointers, with undefined behaviour.

Comment: To match question author's requirements a `std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>>` appears to be most appropriate (note the comments: `wchar_t***` is actually desired type.

Answer (score 0):

```
# include<iostream>
# include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{   

 int m[10][10],row,col,i,j;
 cout<<"enter the row limit";
cin>>row;
cout<<"enter the column limit";
cin>>col;
cout<<"enter the element\n";
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
 {
for(j=0;j<col;j++)
   {
    cin>>m[i][j];
    }
   }
   cout<<"output of  a 2D Array\n";
 for(i=0;i<row;i++)
  {
   for(j=0;j<col;j++)
   {
        cout<<m[i][j]<<" ";
    }
      cout<<"\n";
    }


     getch();

     }
```